# nginx microcaching / cache ONLY primary visit

Tags: caching, nginx

I was reading up on nginx microcaching / cache when the following question struck me: is it possible to cache a 1st visit version of a page?

In other words. We run Magento which is high load, high on resources. This has a reason of course: webstores are dynaimc & customers can select/filter and buy things. Only: isn't the first visit version of a website always the same?

Hence my question: Is it possible to cache a 1st visit version of a page?

- first visit: shows cached optimized for speed version (no session exists)
- each visit after that: shows Magento as is

I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

Am I doing something strange here?

el.1 I set this before server block

```
fastcgi_cache_path /var/run/nginx-cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=MAGENTO:100m inactive=60m;
fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";
fastcgi_cache_use_stale error timeout invalid_header http_500;
fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie;
```

el.2 default skip cache = 0 set it in the server block, skip if session cookies found (so after a first visit) and skip if query or post

```
set $skip_cache 0;

    if ($http_cookie ~* "frontend_cid|frontend|sid|adminhtml") {
     set $skip_cache 1;
    }

if ($request_method = POST) {
        set $skip_cache 1;
    }   
    if ($query_string != "") {
        set $skip_cache 1;
    }
```

el.3 Read from cache using php-fpm as location match in the server block

```
location ~ \.php$ {
   try_files $uri =404;
   fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
   fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
   include fastcgi_params;

   fastcgi_cache_bypass $skip_cache;
   fastcgi_no_cache $skip_cache;

   fastcgi_cache MAGENTO;
   fastcgi_cache_valid  60m;
```

The result seems to be. 1st visit being a visitor without a Magento cookie set either admin or frontend user is getting a cached version. All other get a normal Magento version.

In short: 1st visit = cached version, then session cookie is set (hmmm is the session cookie dynamic or are we all getting the same cookie??). If a cookie is found then we skip the cache.